# Getting multiple "writing index record file: failed to create temporary file" to derived data when building a swift package project

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

Whenever I try to build this swift package project I keep getting multiple lines of errors like the one below.

writing index record file: failed to create temporary file: /Users/"USER"/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pod/Index.noindex/DataStore/v5/records/UD/arm64e-apple-macos.swiftinterface-2I3HRKSNX1HUD-temp-553e9023

My understanding of this issue so far is that xcode is having trouble writing to the derived data folder but not sure why.

I've done the following

1. Clean Build
2. Checked permissions in my Derived Data folder.
3. Delete Derived Data
4. Checked to see if the targets and dependencies were added correctly in the Package.swift file
5. Updated Xcode and restarted both Xcode and my computer
6. Tried changing minimum Swift Tools Version used before changing it back(Note: Weird thing is if I try to use swift tools 5.8 I get a different error saying one of my dependencies can't be found which is a completely new error message. The original minimum version I was using is 5.3)
7. Deleted files in the modulecache folder

None of this worked and I continue to get the same errors about having trouble writing to derived data with these temporary files.
Does anyone have any other suggestions for a fix?